# Length of commutators in the free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

Let $G=F_2$ be the free group of rank $2$. Is there a constant $c>0$ such that the word length $|[u,v]|$ of every commutator $[u,v]=uvu^{-1}v^{-1}$ where $u,v\in G$, $|u|,|v|>0$ is at least $c(|u|+|v|)$ unless $[u,v]=[u_1,v_1]$ for some $u_1,v_1$ with $|u_1|+|v_1|<|u|+|v|$?

Comment: Let $c_0$ be the smallest such constant (so $0\le c_0<2$ and the question is whether $c_0>0$): what is the best upper bound you know on $c_0$? And do you conjecture some precise value for $c_0$?

Comment: I might be missing something in my argument but to me it seems that every $[u,v]$ has a minimal representative of the form $[u_1,v_1]$, where $|[u_1,v_1]|=2(|u_1|+|v_1|)$, is this incorrect?

Comment: @user127776: It might be true. How did you prove that?

Comment: I had an argument using covering spaces. I think you can prove that the covering space corresponding to the commutator subgroup of wedge of two circles is a lattice (\mathbb{Z}^2). Then you lift a commutator to this lattice, it becomes a loop. The important thing is that loops in a lattice are very rigid, there is not much wiggle room, for every loop in the lattice you can assign a minimal loop (by cancelling the parts of loop that for example goes from vertex $x$ to $y$ then immediately goes from $y$ to $x$). Now I think it is not hard to see the minimal loop itself is a commutator and has

Comment: the minimum perimeter among the representatives of the chosen loop in the lattice. Its image in the wedge of circles can be generated by a word of length $2(|u_1|+|v_1|)$ i.e. the perimeter. Now I think it is not hard to check that this is the minimal word length. (if there is a shorter representative its lift to the lattice will give us a loop with smaller perimeter which is a contradiction.)(I might be missing some details ...)

Comment: @user127776: Isn't it true that the lift of every element of the derived subgroup is a loop. How do you distinguish commutators?

Comment: Loops corresponding to commutators are similar to a parallelogram, (you need two word vectors to form this parallelogram)

Comment: @user127776: I would expect a proof which is similar but uses curves on a torus with boundary and Dehn twists.

Comment: @user127776: It is not clear why after cancelations applied to a parallelogram, you still get a parallelogram.

Comment: @MarkSapir Yes this was dependent heavily on my intuition rather than rigorous proof. But the idea is that in order to get the minimal loop, we need to remove certain imperfections (double crossings) from sides (and maybe on the corners too), and because of the symmetry of the initial parallelogram type loop  these cancellations can be applied in symmetric fashion so that it still becomes a parallelogram (once there are no double crossings it means we have the minimal loop).

Comment: @user127776: "these cancellations can be applied in symmetric fashion". I am not sure about that.

Comment: @user127776: What if $u, v$ are members of the derived subgroup themselves. Then the parallelogram looks weird.

Comment: @user127776: I think your argument is basically correct when the core graph of the subgroup $\langle u,v\rangle$ is the figure-8 graph. However, you also need to analyse the two other cases, when it's the theta graph or the spectacles graph. I think the correct statement is that the length of the commutator is twice the number of edges in the core graph, but since edges in the core graph can be used by both $u$ and $v$, the constant that you get will be smaller than 2 (maybe 1?).

Comment: @HJRW: This may be (for every word $w$ instead of the commutator) in a paper by Sela or even by Razborov.

Comment: @MarkSapir: I doubt there's anything quantitative in a paper by Sela! He may prove somewhere that some $c>0$ works. But I think there's probably an elementary argument.

Comment: @HJRW: I will ask Sela. A statement I asked only for arbitrary system of equations should follow from Makanin-Razborov with recurive instead of linear estimate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Victor Guba sent me a proof. The proof is based on the old result by Wicks,  Wicks, N. J. Commutators in free products. J. London Math. Soc. 37 (1962), 433–444.,  which describes all words which are commutators in a free group (Lemma 5 in the paper). By that result, a word is a commutator iff it is a conjugate of a reduced word of the form $ABCA^{-1}B^{-1}C^{-1}$. This immediately implies that one can take $c=1/4$ (possibly bigger).